# numpy matrix multiplication raises weird error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

The following surprisingly fails:

```
# in a loop
.
try:
    pressure_book[element] = c @ np.matrix([1] + point).T
except TypeError as e:
    print(c, type(c), d.type)
    print(point, type(point))
    raise e
.
.
```

And outputs:

```
[[-1.52088384e+08  5.39161089e+03  9.08576658e+03 -3.23303777e-01]] <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'> float64
[26088.6210156483, 17551.050000000003, 457882691.876694] <class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/evkouni/Desktop/PythonGIT/trials.py", line 111, in <module>
    raise e
  File "C:/Users/evkouni/Desktop/PythonGIT/trials.py", line 106, in <module>
    pressure_book[element] = c @ np.matrix([1] + point).T
TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

However, when I try the values in the console, it works just fine.

```
>>> c = np.matrix([[-1.52088384e+08, 5.39161089e+03, 9.08576658e+03, -3.23303777e-01]])
>>> point = [26088.6210156483, 17551.050000000003, 457882691.876694]
>>> c @ np.matrix([1] + point).T
matrix([[849.00029883]])
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

> EDIT: it seems `np.matrix([1] + point).dtype` returns `object` after a couple of iterations of being `float64`

---

<sub>In case it is relevant, I am running this using Python 3.5, numpy 1.15.4 from PyCharm 2018.3</sub>

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `pressure_book` (in `__getitem__`)? Have you checked the exception stack trace?

Comment: Is the error in `c @ np.matrix([1] + point).T` or in `pressure_book[element]` assignment? what does `type(pressure_book)` or `pressure_book[0]` return?

Comment: One or both of the arguments to the `@` operator is an object dtype array.  The error says it can't do that.  While you might be able to substitute `np.dot`, you really should pin down that array dtype.  Evidently your console test is not replicating that condition.

Comment: What is `c.dtype`?

Comment: @jdehesa But I am not trying to retrieve an item from the dict. Only to add. How can `__getitem__` be an issue? Also there is no more stack trace to examine. That is all.

Comment: @hpaulj It is `float64`. See edit.

Comment: @Brenlla `pressure_book` is a dictionary and by the time the above fails, it contains a number of key-value pairs added the exact same way.

Comment: Surprisingly, `np.matrix([1] + point).dtype` sometimes has `.dtype` of `object`..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that depending on what<sup>1</sup> `point` contains, the conversion to `numpy.matrix` with the `dtype` unspecified might yield `object`.

`object`-`dtype` arrays \ matrices do not support matrix multiplication.

To solve this issue, the `dtype` has to be specified as such:

```
c @ np.matrix([1] + point, dtype='float64').T
```

Also, `numpy` claims that the use of the `numpy.matrix` class is not recommended and `numpy.array` should be used instead.

> Note
>
> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
>   algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the
>   future.

Taken from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html?highlight=numpy%20matrix#numpy.matrix)

---

<sup>1</sup>`numpy` states: *"If not given [dtype], then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence."*